# How do i get list of subdirectories contains specific file (ie. '__main__.py) using Python

Tags: python, linux, command, subprocess

hey guys I'm trying to get list of subdirectory that contains specific file in python ??

I used subprocess.call()
and passing find Command,

```
subprocess.call(['find','.','-name','__main__.py'])
```

but it prints path("./directory/file") in terminal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `subprocess.call`, you can get the output of the command:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['find','.','-name','__main__.py'])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    output = '' # fallback output
```

`output` is a string. You may need to split lines to process each file.

```
filelist = output.splitlines()
```

To only get the name of the directory that contain the file, use [`os.path.dirname`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
import os
for filepath in filelist:
    dirpath = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    # Do something with `dirpath`
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but it gives me continuous string and it really messy to extract name of subdirectory that contain '__main__.py' file

Comment: @user3321823, I updated the answer a few minute ago. Please check out the updated content.

Comment: oh yes I just got your updated answer after placing comment thank you it's working...

Comment: oh sure I will do and if you think it's proper question accept quesion,and one more thing I want to ask you are not using .append() then why it's creating list?

Comment: @user3321823, I used [`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) which returns a list that contains substring split by newline. Following a link, you will find a detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an external subprocess, you could find the directories using pure Python:

```
import os

dirs = [root for root, _, filenames in os.walk('.')
        for filename in filenames if filename == '__main__.py']
```

Replace `[]` by `()` if you want to get the directories names lazily.

`subprocess` also allows to get the names on the fly:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['find', '.', '-name', '__main__.py'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
for path in p.stdout:
    print(os.path.dirname(path)) # do something with the dirpath

p.stdout.close()
rc = p.wait()
```

Note: unlike the pure Python version it breaks if there is a path to `__main__.py` with newline in it.